# Jquery block UI not working when used twice?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-blockui

I am using jquery block UI plugin, my requirement is to check if user is authorized user or not, here is my code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnsubmit').click(function () {
                $.blockUI({ css: {
                    border: 'none',
                    padding: '15px',
                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                    '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                    '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                    opacity: .5,
                    color: '#fff'
                }
                });
            });
        }); 

     function ajaxAuth() {
       //UserLogin.IServiceLogin.HelloWorldCC(OnSuccess, OnFailure);
         var usrname = document.getElementById('txtusrname').value;
         var pasd = document.getElementById('txtpassword').value;
         UserLogin.IServiceLogin.GetUseCred(usrname, pasd, onSuccess, onFailed);
     }

     function onSuccess(result) {
         setTimeout($.unblockUI, 0);
         var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

         if (obj.name != "error" ) {
             document.getElementById('labusr').value = obj.name;
             document.getElementById('labpass').value = obj.passd;
             document.getElementById('labkey').value = obj.key;
             location.href = "DesignAPage.aspx";
         } else {
             $.blockUI({ message: $('#question'), css: { width: '350px'} });

//             $('#ok').click(function () {
//                 $.unblockUI();
//                 return false;
//             }); 
         }
     }

     function onFailed(result) {
         alert("failure");
     }

    </script>
```

so the problem is while i am using  `$.blockUI({ message: $('#question'), css: { width: '350px'} });` it just blocks the screen for a second and unblocks the screen.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Try with unblockUI befor blockUI, it may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing this in else block

```
else {
             $.unblockUI({
                 onUnblock: function () {
                     $.blockUI({ message: $('#question'), css: {
                         border: 'none',
                         padding: '15px',
                         backgroundColor: '#000',
                         '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                         '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                         opacity: .5,
                         color: '#fff'
                     }
                     });
                     $('#ok').click(function () {
                         $.unblockUI();
                         return false;
                     }); 
                   }
             }); 
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is being caused by `setTimeout($.unblockUI, 0);`.  Even though you might think that calling this would cause the code to attached function to run immediately, it does not.  You can verify this by running the following:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('one');
}, 0);
console.log('two');
```

`two` is logged before `one`.  The reasoning for this is in the way JavaScript handles  timers internally.  Since it is single threaded, nothing ever runs concurrently. Passing 0 milliseconds to `setTimeout` will just force the function to run at the first available moment.  In this case that's right after `$.blockUI` is called.

John Resig has a nice write up on this at http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/.

Answer (score 0):

I chopped your code up a bit but this is working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.blockUI({ css: { 
    border: 'none', 
    padding: '15px', 
    backgroundColor: '#000', 
    '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
    '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
    opacity: .5, 
    color: '#fff' 
    } 
    }); 

    onSuccess();

});

function onSuccess() { 
$.unblockUI();

$.blockUI({ message: "Some message", css: { width: '350px'} }); 

}
```